# An error occurred while installing package gcc-7 in anaconda

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, anaconda

I'm setting up a new server,and want to install gcc-5/6/7.I don't have root access to the server,so I chose conda to install my own env.However,some mistakes have occurred.Does anyone know how to solve them?

I ran the command "conda install -v -c quantstack gcc-7"

The output is shown below:

An unexpected error has occurred.
Please consider posting the following information to the
conda GitHub issue tracker at:

```
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues
```

Current conda install:

```
           platform : linux-64                                                                                                                                                                                   
      conda version : 4.3.30                                                                                                                                                                                     
   conda is private : False                                                                                                                                                                                      
  conda-env version : 4.3.30                                                                                                                                                                                     
conda-build version : 3.10.5                                                                                                                                                                                     
     python version : 3.6.5.final.0                                                                                                                                                                              
   requests version : 2.18.4                                                                                                                                                                                     
   root environment : /mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3  (writable)                                                                                                                                                    
default environment : /mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_1_0                                                                                                                                               
   envs directories : /mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/envs                                                                                                                                                           
                      /home/heyue/.conda/envs                                                                                                                                                                    
      package cache : /mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/pkgs                                                                                                                                                           
                      /home/heyue/.conda/pkgs                                                                                                                                                                    
       channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/quantstack/linux-64                                                                                                                                             
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/quantstack/noarch                                                                                                                                               
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/menpo/linux-64                                                                                                                         
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/menpo/noarch                                                                                                                           
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/msys2/linux-64                                                                                                                         
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/msys2/noarch                                                                                                                           
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/linux-64                                                                                                                   
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/noarch                                                                                                                     
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch/linux-64                                                                                                                       
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch/noarch                                                                                                                         
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/linux-64                                                                                                                           
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/noarch                                                                                                                             
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64                                                                                                                                               
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch                                                                                                                                                 
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64                                                                                                                                               
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch                                                                                                                                                 
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64                                                                                                                                                  
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch                                                                                                                                                    
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64                                                                                                                                                
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch                                                                                                                                                  
        config file : /home/heyue/.condarc                                                                                                                                                                       
         netrc file : None                                                                                                                                                                                       
       offline mode : False                                                                                                                                                                                      
         user-agent : conda/4.3.30 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Linux/3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64 CentOS Linux/7.2.1511 glibc/2.17                                                                               
            UID:GID : 15665:15665
```

`$ /mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_1_0/bin/conda install -v -c quantstack gcc-7`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 497, in run_script                                                                                                     
    subprocess_call(command_args, env=env, path=dirname(path))                                                                                                                                                   
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/gateways/subprocess.py", line 56, in subprocess_call                                                                                       
    output=_format_output(command_str, path, rc, stdout, stderr))                                                                                                                                                
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/bin/bash', '-x', '/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_1_0/bin/.gcc-7-post-link.sh']' returned non-zero exit status 2.                                            

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                              

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 327, in _execute_actions                                                                                               
    run_script(target_prefix, Dist(pkg_data), 'post-unlink' if is_unlink else 'post-link')                                                                                                                       
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 513, in run_script                                                                                                     
    raise LinkError(message)                                                                                                                                                                                     
conda.exceptions.LinkError: post-link script failed for package quantstack::gcc-7-7.2.0-2                                                                                                                        
running your command again with `-v` will provide additional information                                                                                                                                         
location of failed script: /mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_1_0/bin/.gcc-7-post-link.sh                                                                                                                  
==> script messages <==                                                                                                                                                                                          
<None>
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 281, in execute
    pkg_data, actions)
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 344, in _execute_actions
    reverse_excs,
conda.CondaMultiError: post-link script failed for package quantstack::gcc-7-7.2.0-2
running your command again with `-v` will provide additional information
location of failed script: /mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_1_0/bin/.gcc-7-post-link.sh
==> script messages <==
<None>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 640, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 140, in _main
    exit_code = args.func(args, p)
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 80, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 326, in install
    execute_actions(actions, index, verbose=not context.quiet)
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/plan.py", line 828, in execute_actions
    execute_instructions(plan, index, verbose)
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/instructions.py", line 247, in execute_instructions
    cmd(state, arg)
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/instructions.py", line 108, in UNLINKLINKTRANSACTION_CMD
    txn.execute()
  File "/mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/link.py", line 297, in execute
    rollback_excs,
conda.CondaMultiError: post-link script failed for package quantstack::gcc-7-7.2.0-2
running your command again with `-v` will provide additional information
location of failed script: /mnt/lustre/heyue/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_1_0/bin/.gcc-7-post-link.sh
==> script messages <==
<None>
```

conda install -v -c quantstack gcc-7

I expect the version of the gcc to be 5 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

I got gcc v7, using miniconda v4.7.12:

```sh
conda install -c anaconda gcc_linux-64
```

More details here: https://www.anaconda.com/utilizing-the-new-compilers-in-anaconda-distribution-5/

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/gcc_linux-64/files

```sh
$ x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc --version
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc (crosstool-NG 1.23.0.449-a04d0) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: I followed you, but after installation, the conda env was using the same old system gcc

Comment: conda sets some environment variables too to point to the updated gcc version; you might want to take a look at those environment variables too and make sure they're used in your build commands